# QGIS automatically scrolls only almost to the end to the attribute table

Tags: qgis

When I have the attribute table open with'Show selected features', scrolled to the end of it and then select a new feature which then pops up in the table, QGIS always slightly scrolls back, so that the last number in the last column isn't visible anymore. For example, in the image, in the last field, there is a number, but as QGIS scrolled slighty back, it is not visible.
Is this a bug?

QGIS 3.28 Firenze
Windows 10

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this, but a quick workaround would be to right click on the column name and select 'autosize'